# publishing public pages - design - static vs. php generated

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to determine when to provide static HTML vs. when to generate HTML as needed by PHP.  By that I mean when a user requests a page, is it already waiting in HTML form or is it generated by PHP, and then sent as HTML.

More specifically, what is the best option for user public pages similar to your public pages for Facebook, Linked In or similar.

If the page is for the "content generator" it needs to be generated by PHP as the content is dynamic.  The assumption or general case assumes that the user updates his data as needed or at each login.

If the page is for the "content requestor" of the user's data the page is static...it does not change as long as the user has not logged in and changed it.  Hence it would make some sense to generate a static file in HTML that is served to the the requester of the user's data.  Suppose there are 10 or so requests for the public page in between the generator's login sessions...this would save 10 server "loads" to generate the data as they are already waiting in static form.

Please note the distinction between the user generating the content "the generator" and the user requesting a public type page - "the requester"

I would like to know if someone can validate this approach.  Generating Static Files of HTML that are used in between "generator" updates.  This is a validation question.  Is this a valid approach?

Comment: The question makes no any sense. There is absolutely no difference for the client.

Comment: @zerkms as far as I can tell he is talking about caching php generated content as static html to be served by the server. if valid cache exists, require static cache and done, else generate content, then cache it as a static file for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just about any web application that includes any dynamic information at all, even stuff like printing the day's date at the top or filling in a copyright notice at the bottom, will use dynamically generated pages.

However that doesn't mean that the pages are dynamically loaded on each page load. Instead, there may be some caching going on to limit the server's workload regenerating mostly-static content. (Talking about caching the generated content on the server here, not in the browser's cache). Templating systems like Smarty do this, and most CMS systems will have some sort of cache machinery to do this as well.

You will want to look into PHP caching mechanisms.

However, this is only necessary if your website is not scaling appropriately right now.  In other words, don't worry about caching unless your server cannot keep up with the current load.

**Edit**: For clarity, this kind of caching is unrelated to opcode caching, and is used instead to pre-render as HTML compute-intensive or database-intensive data.  The cached file is served to clients until it is deemed to be expired, then the full page rendering must take place again, hitting the database for up to date data.

Comment: I've heard of opcode caching are you referring to this or something different?

Comment: @GuyMontag No, not opcode caching, but rather caching PHP output as HTML.  Then on subsequent requests until the cache is expired, the output file (which may be a combination of HTML & PHP, but with database content already loaded) is loaded from disk and served to the client.

Comment: "even stuff like printing the day's date at the top or filling in a copyright notice at the bottom" — Two things you shouldn't do. The former because computers have built in clocks and a date on a page looks like a publication time rather than the current time. The latter because copyright applies from the time the content was created, not when it was last sent to a visitor.

Comment: @Quentin the implication is that the _computer_ is the one filling in the date, not a human entering it...

Comment: @Michael — How does a copyright notice that claims the copyright extends from the current year imply that it was filled in by a computer? How does having the date filled in by a computer make it OK to claim copyright from the wrong year?

Comment: @Quentin these were meant to be examples of simple header/footer info which are added to many sites, but not necessarily updated by humans. If the copyright issue bothers you so much, please edit it out of my answer.  This is a technical explanation, not a legal one.

Comment: I'm writing code with no external libraries or cms(s)...so if I use php file functions and 'fwrite' the file then later serve it...this would be the same as caching... correct?  Or is there a better way than fwrite?

Comment: @GuyMontag If you create the HTML output and write it to a file, yes that is like caching it. I assume you'll check an expiration date on the file and regenerate occasionally.  `file_put_contents()` is a bit easier than `fopen()/fwrite()`.

Comment: I've made my life easier...by removing the view from the server all together, it is just a data-pump...I compose the view on the client...now for public pages..I simply modify my view on the client...in other words..no need to cache...when there is nothing to cache.